# Virtualbox.org site unavailable

Tags: virtualbox, internet, connection, websites

from weeks ago the site virtualbox.org (and all the related subdomains, i.e.: download.virtualbox.org) seems to be down. The oddest thing is that there are 0 comments in the web about this.

Does someone knows anything about this?

Cheers
/JL

Comment: It works for me; check http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.virtualbox.org. Pretty sure it is just you.

Comment: The site is not down, that's why there are no comments. Also what does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Works for me as well - so debug on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! wow, I have no idea why my DNS is not resolving that, have to check. I should have checked before, sorry for bothering!

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this happen to a number of people when I was an active moderator on Vatsim, who has thousands of members.  They would have a friend contact us that they couldn't access the site.

You can also find out that it's very common with a quick Google search:
https://www.google.com/#q=can%27t+connect+to+a+particular+website

The problem was resolved differently for different people.

Some of the things you can test is:

- Trying to access the site via it's IP address.  You can get the IP address with:
  `$ host virtualbox.org`
  http://137.254.60.32
  Of course if that works, check your DNS setting.  You might try a public DNS server such as google's `8.8.8.8`.
- Try a different browser.
- While you have already verified the site isn't down by asking others (us) to check, you could also check by using a different network such as your cell phone's data connection.
- Try connecting via a different network such as your phone's tether.
- Try connecting using a proxy:
  https://www.google.com/#q=public+proxy+list
- Reset your router.
- Contact your ISP and ask them to assist in checking.